# LiveObjectService#persist returns empty object

Tags: java, redis, redisson

I'm using the Redisson Live Objects 3.13.2 and I have the following object:

```
@Getter
@ToString
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@REntity
public class ReporterObject {
    @RId
    private long id;
    private long rId;
    @RIndex
    @Setter
    private long sId;
    @Setter
    private boolean ac;
    @RIndex
    @Setter
    private Long parId;
    private int type;
    private Long pId;
    @Setter
    private ReporterObject parent; // can be null
    @Setter
    private int n_a = 0;
}
```

So I have two problems:

1. When I this operation(to override the current object):

```
liveObjectService.delete(ReporterObject.class, reporterObject.getRId());
return liveObjectService.persist(reporterObject);
```

I sometimes get `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: This REntity already exists.` although I'm performing a deletion beforehand. I can get it even if the cache is totally empty before then.

2. Sometimes after the persist operation supposedly succeed, what I receive is an empty object so when I try to get any field(for example call `ReporterObject#getParent` a `NullPointerException` is  being thrown and when I debug it, I see an empty object or not "fully full" object:
   [image]
   . In this example I only have `sId` and `type` but no `id` , no `rId`, no `ac` etc. As I stated, If I try to `getAc()` a `NullPointerException` is thrown. Of course it's not limited to this fields only. Sometimes it's other fields that are missing. Sometimes I get a fully empty object like this one:
   [image]

Redis version is 6.0.5.

Any ideas on what to do in this case?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using a read-replica for redis? If so, this might be caused by a delay between the syncing of master-slave

Comment: @AwesomeHunter no, it is a standalone redis server, so it can't be the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Opened a bug which was resolved:
https://github.com/redisson/redisson/issues/2935